# Limited SFTP access under Debian

Tags: debian, remote-access, user-management

under debian, I want to create a user who can only access to a specific folder (ie /home/user/some/folder/ (this folder already exists) , can do anything that he wants like modify, create delete a file) and no privilidge to any other stuff beside the given folder.

How can I achieve this under the standart Debian Lenny for SFTP ?

Answer (score 2):

[Here you go](http://www.howtoforge.com/chrooted-ssh-sftp-tutorial-debian-lenny).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to take the hassle of setting up chroots just to lock down SFTP/SCP access, you should take a look at those two packages:

- [scponly](http://packages.debian.org/sid/scponly)
- [rssh](http://packages.debian.org/sid/rssh)

They provide you with enough options to limit several actions inside a SSH session. Both are meant for being used as a shell for selected users.